# Unable to execute the Connected Object/ Island program

Tags: c

I have written a program that identifies islands in a 2D integer matrix. An island is a collection of 1s placed in such a way each 1 is next to at least another 1 within the surrounding 8 cells. The program works fine for any array except when the concerned 1 is in the last row and the search for surrounding 1s goes beyond the last row of the array.

This is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void objectCount(int **arr, int row, int col, int i, int j)
{
    *(*(arr+i)+j) = -1; //Mark as visited
    int p,q;
    //Search for surrounding 8 cells
    for(p=i-1;p<=i+1;p++)
        for(q=j-1;q<=j+1;q++)
        {
            printf("\n\tTesting position %d,%d",p+1,q+1);
            //Condition to ensure search is within array boundaries, excluding the visited cell
            if((p!=i||q!=j) && !(p<0||q<0) && arr[p][q]==1 && (p<row && q<col))
            {
                printf("\n\t\tGoing to mark %d,%d",p+1,q+1);
                objectCount(arr,row,col,p,q); //Recursively call the function from the newly identified cell with 1
                printf("\n\t\tMarking %d,%d",p+1,q+1);
            }
            printf("\tTested position %d,%d",p+1,q+1);
        }
}
int islands(int **arr, int m, int n)
{
    int count=0,i,j;
    //Go through all the elements in the array
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            if(*(*(arr+i)+j)==1)
            {
                count++;
                printf("\nGroup spotted at %d,%d",i+1,j+1);
                objectCount(arr,m,n,i,j); //To mark the entire island with -1
            }
    return count;
}
void main()
{
    int m,n,i,j;
    printf("Enter number of rows:\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Enter number of columns:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int **a = malloc((m+1)*sizeof(int *));
    printf("Enter the matrix:\n");
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        *(a+i) = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            scanf("%d",(*(a+i)+j));
    }
    printf("Number of connected objects = %d",islands(a,m,n));
}
```

This is the output I get

```
Enter number of rows:
3
Enter number of columns:
3
Enter the matrix:
1 1 0
0 0 0
1 0 1

Group spotted at 1,1
        Testing position 0,0    Tested position 0,0
        Testing position 0,1    Tested position 0,1
        Testing position 0,2    Tested position 0,2
        Testing position 1,0    Tested position 1,0
        Testing position 1,1    Tested position 1,1
        Testing position 1,2
                Going to mark 1,2
        Testing position 0,1    Tested position 0,1
        Testing position 0,2    Tested position 0,2
        Testing position 0,3    Tested position 0,3
        Testing position 1,1    Tested position 1,1
        Testing position 1,2    Tested position 1,2
        Testing position 1,3    Tested position 1,3
        Testing position 2,1    Tested position 2,1
        Testing position 2,2    Tested position 2,2
        Testing position 2,3    Tested position 2,3
                Marking 1,2     Tested position 1,2
        Testing position 2,0    Tested position 2,0
        Testing position 2,1    Tested position 2,1
        Testing position 2,2    Tested position 2,2
Group spotted at 3,1
        Testing position 2,0    Tested position 2,0
        Testing position 2,1    Tested position 2,1
        Testing position 2,2    Tested position 2,2
        Testing position 3,0    Tested position 3,0
        Testing position 3,1    Tested position 3,1
        Testing position 3,2    Tested position 3,2
        Testing position 4,0    Tested position 4,0
        Testing position 4,1
--------------------------------
Process exited after 26.35 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is how the output should be for a different, but similar input

```
Enter number of rows: 
3
Enter number of columns: 
4 
Enter the matrix: 
1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1
1 1 0 1
Number of connected objects = 3
```

The lines "testing position" and "marking" were just added to see where the error happens. Somehow the program gets stuck at the if condition when dealing with the last row. Any ideas how to find the problem and solve it.

I have already seen other examples at various sites like geeksforgeeks for instance, but I want to know why this program doesn't run.

Comment: you must avoid exceeding the array bounds in `objectCount()`

Comment: You need to do the bounds checking *before* you access the array; swap `arr[p][q]==1 && (p<row && q<col)` around

Comment: @ChrisTurner It worked! How does checking the array bound first change anything? The previous arrangement worked fine while checking out-of-bound columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order matters due to [short circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). If you have an if statement like

```
if(p<row && q<col)
```

if `p<row` is false, it won't bother evaluating `q<col` as no matter what the outcome of that would be, it could never make the entire expression be true. This is important to remember if you have any expressions in `if` statements that alter variables in some fashion.

However if `p<row` is true, it will continue on and also check `q<col`.

So by putting the `(p<row && q<col)` before the check of `arr[p][q]==1` if `p` or `q` are out of bounds, it won't bother. So change your `if` statement like this and you'll avoid any further out of bound issues with it.

```
if((p!=i||q!=j) && p>=0 && q>=0 && p<row && q<col && arr[p][q]==1)
```